# Why doesn't nbsp display as nbsp in the URL

Tags: html, urlencode, urldecode

I am following a tutorial where a web application written in PHP, blacklists spaces from the input(The 'id' parameter). The task is to add other characters, which essentially bypasses this blacklist, but still gets interpreted by the MySQL database in the back end. What works is a URL constructed like so -
`http://192.168.2.15/sqli-labs/Less-26/?id=1'%A0||%A0'1`

Now, my question is simply that if '%A0' indicates an NBSP, then why is it that when I go to a site like http://www.url-encode-decode.com, and try to decode the URL `http://192.168.2.15/sqli-labs/Less-26/?id=1'%A0||%A0'1`, it gets decoded as `http://192.168.2.15/sqli-labs/Less-26/?id=1'�||�'1`.

Instead of the question mark inside a black box, I was expecting to see a blank space.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect that this is due to differences between character encodings.

The value `A0` represents `nbsp` in the [ISO-8859-1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO/IEC_8859-1) encoding (and probably in other extended-ASCII encodings too). The page at http://www.url-encode-decode.com appears to use the [UTF-8](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-8) encoding.

Your problem is that there is no character represented by `A0` in UTF-8. The equivalent `nbsp` character in UTF-8 would be represented by the value `C2A0`.

Decoding `http://192.168.2.15/sqli-labs/Less-26/?id=1'%C2%A0||%C2%A0'1` will produce the `nbsp` characters that you expected.

Answer (score 0):

Independently from why there is an encoding error, try **%20** as a replacement for a whitespace!
Later on you can str_replace the whitespace with a

```
echo str_replace(" ", "&nbsp;", $_GET["id"]);
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the script on this site does not work properly. If you use it in your PHP code it should work properly.

`echo urldecode( '%A0' );`

outputs:

`&nbsp;`